# running model.evaluate many times results different accuracy and loss value tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained a CNN network using `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, label))` to create the dataset. training went well but evaluating the model on test dataset results different values every time without changing anything in test dataset or the network and I am not using any `Dropout` or `Batchnormalization`:

If necessary my code:

```
 model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Input((1,30,30)),
    Conv2D(filters = 8, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", name="c1", data_format="channels_first"),
    Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", name="c2", data_format="channels_first"),
    MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(1,1),padding="same", name="m1", data_format="channels_first"),

    Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", name="c3", data_format="channels_first"),
    MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(1,1),padding="same", name="m2",data_format="channels_first"),

    Flatten(),
    Dense(256, activation="relu", use_bias=True),
    Dense(5,  use_bias=True)])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_data, verbose=1, validation_data=valid_data, epochs=20)


model.evaluate(test_data)
```

How I made the Dataset:

```
def split_dataset(dataset: tf.data.Dataset, validation_data_fraction: float):

    validation_data_percent = round(validation_data_fraction * 100)
    if not (0 <= validation_data_percent <= 100):
        raise ValueError("validation data fraction must be ∈ [0,1]")

    dataset = dataset.enumerate()
    train_dataset = dataset.filter(lambda f, data: f % 100 >= validation_data_percent)
    validation_dataset = dataset.filter(lambda f, data: f % 100 < validation_data_percent)

    # remove enumeration
    train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda f, data: data)
    validation_dataset = validation_dataset.map(lambda f, data: data)

    return train_dataset, validation_dataset

def load_data(path):
    data, label = data_prep(path)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, label))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(100000)
    train_dataset, rest = split_dataset(dataset, 0.3)
    test_dataset, valid_dataset = split_dataset(rest, 0.5)
    train_data = train_dataset.shuffle(1000).batch(10)
    valid_data = valid_dataset.batch(10)
    test_data = test_dataset.batch(10)
    return train_data, valid_data, test_data
```

for example running `model.evaluate(test_data)` gives:

```
885/Unknown - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1039 - accuracy: 0.9663
885/Unknown - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0959 - accuracy: 0.9675
885/Unknown - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0999 - accuracy: 0.9661
885/Unknown - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0888 - accuracy: 0.9688
885/Unknown - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0799 - accuracy: 0.9715
```

Comment: When you mention "evaluating the model every time", are you also re-training the model? Because, if you are executing the same code over and over the results would be different due to the randomness in the weights of the network.

Comment: I dont train anymore. it's already trained. but still I get different evaluation on the same test dataset ofcourse.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your first shuffle of the whole dataset. Can you inspect your `test_data` just before calling `model.evaluate(test_data)` by calling something like `list(test_data.as_numpy_array())`? My assumption would be, that this would yield different results every time you call it. In other words: your model is fine, but your dataset is different each time, most likely, because you use [`dataset.shuffle`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) without `seed` and without deactivating `reshuffle_each_iteration`. While the former explains differences between runs, the latter explains differences within runs.

My suggestion would something like:

````py
seed = 42

def load_data(path):
    data, label = data_prep(path)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, label))
    # shuffle your dataset **once**, but reliably so that each run yields the same results
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(100000, seed=seed, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
    train_dataset, rest = split_dataset(dataset, 0.3)
    test_dataset, valid_dataset = split_dataset(rest, 0.5)
    # (re)shuffle only the training set, but again, using a seed
    train_data = train_dataset.shuffle(1000, seed=seed).batch(10)
    valid_data = valid_dataset.batch(10)
    test_data = test_dataset.batch(10)
    return train_data, valid_data, test_data
```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you train your model and then run `model.evaluate` $N$ times (do not retrain the model) you should get the same answer each time PROVIDED your test data is the SAME each time. However if you train your model then run evaluate and do that combination $N$ times results will vary due to the random weight initialization of the network.

Comment: exactly. but my problem is that it isn't happening. I trained and finished training my model. that means my weights should not change anymore. but for some task I have to evaluate my network N times. but still my evaluation gives different results. I dont understand this. I thought it might be like Pytorch that one should switch between eval() and train() mode. but I didnt find anything in tf2

Comment: how big is the difference? I don't use Tourch so can't help on that area.Are you sure the test data is the same each time?

Comment: for your first question
885/Unknown - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1039 - accuracy: 0.9663
885/Unknown - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0959 - accuracy: 0.9675
885/Unknown - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0999 - accuracy: 0.9661
885/Unknown - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0888 - accuracy: 0.9688
885/Unknown - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0799 - accuracy: 0.9715

I know its not that much but its important for my task.
as for the second time I was sure. Unless there is something about tf2 dataset that I don't know. Im gonna add the code to generate dataset in the post

Comment: are you using multiple workers? I have read somewhere that can lead to some degree of randomness using a GPU. A reference for getting repeatable results is at https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/. There is also this reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcW0DeWRggs&list=PLZbbT5o_s2xrwRnXk_yCPtnqqo4_u2YGL&index=18.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it wasn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Running model.evaluate should give the same result. This is true. But the number which is printed is not the result of model.evaluate! In order to compare the results of model.evaluate you have to compare the returned values instead.

[image]

Comment: So what is the printed number then?